# App icon not displayed on Nexus 10

Tags: android, android-icons

My app icon is not displayed on the home screen of a Nexus 10 but it is displayed on the home screen of every other device that I run my app on. I have the icon image saved in both my drawable-xhdpi folder and my drawable-xxhdpi folder but still no luck. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this will make a difference, but try adding a drawable-hdpi folder and add the icon. Also make sure the icon is listed under  @drawable/FILENAME in the manifest.

Hope this helps.